# При обновлении приложения удаляются данные сохраненные в ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, mobile-development, microsoft-store

При обновлении (через магазин Microsoft Store) приложения удаляются данные сохраненные в `ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings`. Как можно еще сохранять необходимые данные так, чтобы при обновлении приложения они оставались на месте? Приложение под UWP на Windows 10 (Win 10 Phone).

Пример:
Есть `localSettings.Values["UserId"]`, после обновления он отсутствует вообще.

Comment: Может попробовать RoamingSettings?

Comment: @MakeMakeluv в принципе, как вариант. Но насколько я понимаю это синхронизирующиюся данные. А я храню токен которым я подписываю запросы к серверу имено в локале. И я думаю его синхронизировать не совсем правильно.

Comment: Всякое секретное надо хранить в PasswordVault.

Comment: @MakeMakevul А PassvordVault после обновления тоже обнуляется? Просто я не знаю как имитировать обновления чтобы проверить :)

Comment: Мне кажется не должен обнуляться, потому что в нем всякие ключи хранятся. Так бы из всех сетевых приложений разлогинивало после каждого обновления, если бы хранилище очищалось.